# How to size and position an embedded UIViewController using Auto Layout constraints?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, autolayout, interface-builder, xcode7

Here is what I wanna do:
My storyboard contains a `UIViewController` with just a few controlls. It's height is less than half a screen. For simplicity, let's call it the `DataViewController`. 
The `DataViewController` is embedded inside other `UIViewControllers` through a "`Container View`".

Although "`Container View`" displays the `DataViewController`, it still needs to have an explicit `height` set. Otherwise interface builder complains about ambiguous constraints.

Now, how can I tell "`Container View`" that it's size should be what's required by `DataViewController`? I.e. without setting a hard coded, explicit `height` in Interface Builder (which, I fear, would break the layout if the font size changes)?

Or in other words: How do you size/position embedded `UIViewControllers` in Interface Builder?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want the childViewContainer to be responsible for its width and height, here is a way to do it :

- Set width and height constraints in your Parent View Controller(s) and select remove at build time. They are just here so interface builder stops complaining about missing constraints.
  [image]
- (You can) Change your Child View Controller simulated size from fixed to freeform in your storyboard size inspector tab.

[image]

- Here is the trick : In your Parent View Controller(s) viewDidLoad disable translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints on the first subviews, and simply redefine by yourself the containerView constraints to its subview - root view of your Child View Controller - like bellow :

**Objective-C**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.containerView.subviews[0].translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
}

#pragma mark - Constraints

- (void)updateViewConstraints {
    [super updateViewConstraints];
    [self initConstraints];
}

- (void)initConstraints {
    if (!self.didSetConstraints) {
        self.didSetConstraints = YES;

        self.containerView.subviews[0].translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        NSDictionary *views = @{@"subview" : self.containerView.subviews[0]};

        [self.containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[subview]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
        [self.containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[subview]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    }
}
```

**Swift**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    containerView.subviews[0].translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
}

// Mark: Constraints

override func updateViewConstraints() {
    super.updateViewConstraints()
    initConstraints()
}

func initConstraints() {
    if !didSetConstraints {
        didSetConstraints = true

        containerView.subviews[0].translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let views = ["subview": containerView.subviews[0]]

        containerView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[subview]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views))
        containerView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[subview]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views))
    }
}
```

Now your child View Controller (linked to the container view) is fully responsible for its content size. Thus, you **must** set constraints that let the root view calculates its size to satisfies the constraints it holds.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that! At the end, I've decided to simply copy the controls where ever they are needed rather than (doing it the right way) by just grouping them in a view and reusing that view. It's just way too complicated getting the nested view approach to work properly and I really don't wanna implement a layout manager with apples crappy (crapples) layout constraints. Oh man, this feels so stuck in the 90s... Anyway, thank you for taking the time sharing this! I'm gonna accept it as answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are embedding with a segue, just do:

```swift
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let viewController = segue.destination as? EmbeddedViewController {
      viewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in your content view controller set the `preferredContentSize` (In your example `DataViewController`) like the following

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 400, height: 200)
}
```

When the child gets added to the parentViewController, the parentViewController gets notified about the prefered size. Following function gets called on the parent

`func preferredContentSizeDidChange(forChildContentContainer container: UIContentContainer)`

In this method you can then change the container to the prefered size of the child.
For example change the height to the prefered height of the child/content

```
override func preferredContentSizeDidChange(forChildContentContainer container: UIContentContainer) {
    // heightConstraint is a IBOutlet to your NSLayoutConstraint you want to adapt to height of your content
    heigtConstraint.constant = container.preferredContentSize.height
}
```